# How to select value in jQuery dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, select, html.dropdownlistfor

In this code I'm fetching selected value from the php file and assign it, but it doesn't work every time. Suppose if I refresh it then one value may be assigned and the other one is may be not, sometimes both are not assigned. What is the problem? The `selectedcaste.php` returns the following:

```
{"cast":"BC","busrout":"B20"}
```

For testing purposes I hardcoded it but I face the same problem.

```
$.ajax({url:"phpajax/selectedcaste.php",success:function(result){
    var valoresArea=result; // it has the multiple values to set, separated by comma
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(valoresArea);

    $('#caste').val(obj.cast).attr("selected", "selected");
    $('#route').val(obj.busrout).attr("selected", "selected");


    //$('#caste').select2("val",obj.cast);
    //$('#route').select2("val",obj.busrout);
}});
```

here my full java script

```
$(function(){
    // for loading caste list from database at run time
     var items="";
     $.getJSON("phpajax/caste.php",function(data){
     $.each(data,function(index,item) 
        {

        items+="<option value='"+item.Name+"'>"+item.Name+"</option>";
        });
    $("#caste").html(items); 
  });


    // for loading route  list from database at run time
     var items2="";
     $.getJSON("phpajax/route.php",function(data){
     $.each(data,function(index,item) 
        {

        items2+="<option value='"+item.Name+"'>"+item.Name+"</option>";
        });
    $("#route").html(items2); 
  });



    // assign selected value from records
    $.ajax({url:"phpajax/selectedcaste.php",success:function(result){
    var valoresArea=result; // it has the multiple values to set, separated by comma
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(valoresArea);

     $('#caste').val($.trim(obj.cast)).attr("selected", "selected");
     $('#route').val($.trim(obj.busrout)).attr("selected", "selected");


    //$('#caste').select2("val",obj.cast);
    //$('#route').select2("val",obj.busrout);

  }});


});
```

my html

```
<select name="caste"  id="caste"  style="width: 100%;">
<!--   <option value="0" selected="selected" >Choose an option...</option>-->

</select>
<select name="route"  id="route"   style="width:100%;">                             

</select>
```

error

some time select correctly.
some time select onely one. some time both are not selected. if i use alert statement it every time it alert correctly but not select properly. i am using bootstrap 2.0 theme. 
thanks

Comment: you want to add options in dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of -

```
$('#caste').val(obj.cast).attr("selected", "selected");
$('#route').val(obj.busrout).attr("selected", "selected");
```

Use only -

```
$('#caste').val(obj.cast);
$('#route').val(obj.busrout);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/L4ctn81t/2/)

### **UPDATE-**

You are making `3 ajax request` at the same time `asynchronously`.You can't control order of callbacks when it's `asynchronous`.

Here is the possibility that your `third ajax callback` execute before your `second and first callback` that causing setting the values into the select boxs prior filling options into them.

Hence make sure your `first and second callback` execute before then your `third callback`.

**Use [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to handle multiple ajax callback into single callback**

```
$(function () {
    // for loading caste list from database at run time
    var items = "";
    $.when($.getJSON("phpajax/caste.php"), $.getJSON("phpajax/route.php"))
        .done(function (data1, data2) {//execute when both ajax request completed
        var items = "";
        var items2 = "";
        console.log(data1[0],data2[0]);
        $.each(data1[0], function (index, item) {
            items += "<option value='" + item.Name + "'>" + item.Name + "</option>";
        });
        $("#caste").html(items);//filling 1'st select
        $.each(data2[0], function (index, item) {
            items2 += "<option value='" + item.Name + "'>" + item.Name + "</option>";
        });
        $("#route").html(items2);//filling 2'nd select

        //Making third request for setting values
        $.ajax({url:"phpajax/selectedcaste.php",success:function(result){
        var valoresArea=result; // it has the multiple values to set, separated by comma
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(valoresArea);

        $('#caste').val(obj.cast);
        $('#route').val(obj.busrout);
      }});
});
```

Comment: Please share your html to

Comment: hai . realy i dont know how to share code. the comment so its to big.. guid me how to share code .... <div id="divcast">  
                                  <select name="caste[]" multiple="multiple" id="caste" value="{$caste}" style="width: 100%;">
                                         <!--   <option value="0" selected="selected" >Choose an option...</option>-->
                                                                                                                   
                                  </select>
                                 </div>

Comment: share code by updating your question , share only required code not all and also post the error you are getting

Comment: Are you not adding any option in your select on your server side code??.share your code for adding option :)

Comment: sir in my code the list is added dynamicly. is it affect the selection process?

Comment: hai vikrant. thanks.. its working fine. now. once again thank you very much

Comment: @Ravindr You're welcome! If my answer suited your needs, don't forget to accept it (same for the other questions you asked :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/186921

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`$('#caste').val(obj.cast).attr("selected", "selected");`

Just use

`$('#caste').val(obj.cast);`

Or(sometimes problem occurs like in your case due to white spaces) use `$.trim()` to remove white spaces as shown :-

`$('#caste').val($.trim(obj.cast));`

Comment: problem continued sir... <div id="divcast">  
                                  <select name="caste[]" multiple="multiple" id="caste" value="{$caste}" style="width: 100%;">
                                         <!--   <option value="0" selected="selected" >Choose an option...</option>-->
                                                                                                                   
                                  </select>
                                 </div>